# Best way to replace an enum to maximize compilation time checks

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a rather old application dealing with different kind of currencies. For the moment, currencies are stored in an enum, for example:

```
enum CURRENCY {
  EUR,
  USD,
  CNY
};

double convertMoney(CURRENCY in, CURRENCY out, double money_in) {
   ...
}
```

This is working *great*, except this is not really type safe: I have other functions containing comments such as *`WARNING: all inputs should have the same currency`*. My objective is to replace most of these comments by compile time checks whenever it is possible. I can use C++17 and boost.

I thought of using an `std::variant` such that:

```
class EUR {};
class USD {};
class CNY {};

using CURRENCY = std::variant<EUR,USD,CNY>;

template<typename IN, typename OUT>
class Market {
 public:
   ...
   double convertMoney(double in) {
      return in*rate;
   }
 private:
   void updateRate() {
      ....
      rate = some_value_fetched_at_runtime;
   }
   double rate;
};

int main() {
    Market<EUR, USD> eur_usd;
    Market<EUR, CNY> eur_cny;

    std::vector<Market<CURRENCY,CURRENCY>> all_markets{eur_usd, eur_cny};
    ...
    //do something 
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

But of course, this won't work since I'm trying to push into my vector of Market objects with different types.

So, to sum up, what do you guys think is the best way to replace an enum in modern C++? If using `std::variant` is right, what would be the best way to solve the above problem?

Note that:

1. I could do something like `using Markets = std::variant<Market<EUR,USD>,Market<EUR,CNY>,...>` but this is not really doable in practice since I have around ~100 type of market and this doesn't really improve maintainability.
2. I could make a class `CURRENCY` and have `EUR`, `USD`, `CNY` child classes of `CURRENCY` but this would use v-table at run time which would lower the number of compile time checks. If someone can prove me the contrary, I'm open to it though.
3. All my markets are defined in my source code (I don't need to create a new kind of market dynamically at run time), but the rate is changing dynamically.

Comment: So what do you want to be checked statically?

Comment: 4. You can make each currency a separate (template) class with explicit conversion between them, like they did in ::std::chrono or ::boost::unit.

Comment: Use [enum class](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/4-5a-enum-classes/) instead of enum.

Comment: @yurikilochek a good example of the kind of static checks I want is: If I have 2 objects `eur_cny` and `eur_usd` as above, I would like a compiler error when doing `eur_cny.convertMoney(eur_usd.convertMoney(100))` since I'm trying to use $ as input to `eur_cny` (which should accepts EUR only)

Comment: @VTT do you mean using the `ratio` header? I though about it and it would be nice, but my rates have to change at runtime

Comment: @Yotam AFAIK enum class is useful when having different enums with the same (int) value? Sure it would be better than a simple enum, but I'm hoping there is a way to have more type safety (e.g. let's say i only have one enum in my whole codebase)

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_units.html might be interesting too.

Answer (score 5):

4. You can make each currency a separate (template) class with explicit conversion between them, like they did in ::std::chrono or ::boost::unit.

   ```
   template< CURRENCY VCurrencyId > class
   t_Sum
   {
       public: using
       t_Value = double;

       private: t_Value m_value{};

       public: 
       t_Sum(void)
       {}

       public: 
       t_Sum(t_Sum const & other)
       :   m_value{other.m_value}
       {}

       public: explicit 
       t_Sum(t_Value const & value)
       :   m_value{value}
       {}

       public: t_Sum &
       operator =(t_Sum const & other)
       {
           m_value = other.m_value;
           return(*this);
       }

       public: t_Value const &
       Get_Value(void)
       {
           return(m_value);
       }

       public: void
       Set_Value(t_Value const & value)
       {
           m_value = value;
       }
   };

   template< CURRENCY VInputCurrencyId, CURRENCY VOutputCurrencyId > t_Sum< VOutputCurrencyId >
   Convert(t_Sum< VInputCurrencyId > in) {
       ...
   }

   using
   t_Eur = t_Sum< EUR >;

   using
   t_Usd = t_Sum< USD >;

   t_Eur euros{};
   t_Usd bucks{euros};
   // compile-time error, conversion required!
   // or you can add converting constructor
   ```

Comment: This is definitely the way where I want to go thanks.
The issue I'm having with this, is that I want to be able to call different `Convert` for different markets i.e. if `Convert` belongs to a `Market` class, this `Market` class is going to depend on 2 template parameters, then how to store an array/vector of `Market` each element having different types? This brings back to the issue described in the original post.

Comment: @pierre Shouldn't `Market` class be a regular (non-template) class holding an array of conversion ratios for all the currencies?

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like:

```
enum class CURRENCY {
    EUR = 0,
    USD,
    CNY,
    LAST = CNY     
};

template <CURRENCY cur> class Price;

// Class to handle convertion
class Market
{
public:
    template <CURRENCY Out, CURRENCY In>
    Price<Out> convertMoney(const Price<In>&);

    void updateChange(CURRENCY in, CURRENCY out, double ratio);
private:
    double ratios[int(CURRENCY::Last)][int(CURRENCY::Last)];
};

// Class to represent typed currency value
template <CURRENCY cur>
class Price
{
public:
    explicit Price(double value) : value(value) {}

    // should only be used when we want the value without the type
    double getValue() const { return value; }

    // operation which restrict same currency as
    Price& operator +=(const Price&);
    // ...

private:
    double value;
};
```